# How restore IP in the HP printer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, router

I had a HP printer which was accessed by the IP 192.168.0.150 (which was given by a HUB) , now I put a router NETGEAR, is given IP to every computer, but I can't find the printer anymore in the network.

Even putting the HP software is not working.

Any idea ?

**EDIT:**
It looks like I could find the printer in the network, but see the IP/port that gives to the printer, it looks pretty weird:

[image]

Comment: A hub is a dumb device and does not and never will give out an IP address to a printer.  So there must have been another device on your network handing out DHCP leases, mostl likely with a reserved IP for your printers MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address will probably have been assigned using DHCP. I suggest you have a look on your netgear router and see if there as option to assign a fixed IP address to a MAC address. If you can do that, then you just need to find the MAC address of the HP printer. Its sometimes visible through the onboard menus, or perhaps the printer self test page.

**Edit:** Likewise if you don't have too many machines connected to your lan, you should be able to list the DHCP leases somewhere within the control panel of your router. The ip address it assigned to the printer may be there, and you can work it out by process of elimination if you know the ip addresses of your computers.

Comment: Could be the MAC address the port that it gives to me in the picture that I post ?

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't look like a mac address to me. Here you can find what to look out for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Notational_conventions Most commonly it will look like this: 01:23:45:67:89:ab

Comment: I'm trying to catch the MAC address, but nothing

Comment: You might also see it in the control panel of your router. it will tell you which leases have been assigned to which ips. You can then work out which one it is by process of elimination, as you will know the ip addresses of the computers connected. Actually come to think of it, even the ip address will be there too.....

Comment: +1 Most network-attached (HP) printers allow you to print a network configuration page from the printer itself; this will contain the current network settings on the printer, including the IP address.  
Read your manual to figure out how to do it for your model, and print one out. :)