# How change printer IP address?

Tags: printer, network-printer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How restore ip in the HP printer?](https://superuser.com/questions/370239/how-restore-ip-in-the-hp-printer)

I have a HP Office Jet Pro 8000 A809 which have 192.168.0.150 IP, but I change the gateway to 192.168.1.1 so the printer should have 192.168.1.150, but I cannot find a way to change it.

How can I do that ?

EDIT:
Reading the data sheet from HP, it says :

"Web browser: In a supported Web browser on your computer, type the IP address
or hostname that has been assigned to the device.
For example, if you are using an IPv4 network environment and the IP address is
123.123.123.123, type the following address into the Web browser:
http://123.123.123.123. If you are using an IPv6-only network environment
and the IP address is FE80::BA:D0FF:FE39:73E7, type the following address into
the Web browser: http://[FE80::BA:D0FF:FE39:73E7].
The IP address and hostname for the device are listed on the network or wireless
(some models only) status report. For more information, see Understand the
network configuration or wireless (some models only) status report.
After opening the embedded Web server, you can bookmark it so that you can
return to it quickly in the future"

But I check my router and it didn't gives any ip to my printer..

Comment: Have you tried reading the printer's manual? If it got lost, you can download a copy from HP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

telnet to it and type "?" (I'm assuming it is connected via a JetDirect widget/box/card like most networked HP printers on the planet)

Of course, you will probably have to do this from a PC with an IP-address in the same network as the printer (IP-range and mask). This is why network people have laptops/netbooks/fancy-gadgets

```
$ telnet laser3
Trying 10.0.0.23...
Connected to laser3.
Escape character is '^]'.
HP JetDirect
Password is not set

Please type "menu" for the MENU system,
or "?" for help, or "/" for current settings.
> ?
   Help Menu

      Type one "Command" followed by one of its valid "Values".

      Command:          Values:
      ---------------   --------------------------

      ?                 [displays Help menu]
      /                 [Display current values]
      #                 [Comment Line]
      menu              [Enter Menu]
      advanced          [Enable Advanced commands]
      general           [Disable Advanced commands] (default)
      save              [Save settings and exit]
      exit              [exit]
      export            [Export settings to edit and import via Telnet or TFTP]

      GENERAL____________________________________
      passwd            <new-password> <retype-new-password> (16 chars max)
      sys-location      alpha-numeric string (255 chars max)
      sys-contact       a      security-reset    1 to reset

      TCP/IP MAIN________________________________
      host-name         alpha-numeric string (32 chars max)
      ip-config         MANUAL, BOOTP, DHCP, AUTO_IP
      ip                IP address in dotted notation, 0.0.0.0 to disable
```

Comment: 'laser3' is the name of the printer in the network ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: yes, but you should type your printer's old IP-address 192.168.0.150 instead.

Comment: thanks, I type the Ip of the printer in my web browser and it works.
I had to change the ip of my machine to it has the same subnet as the printer.